# Facebook API page_impressions/page_storytellers by age_gender return empty array

Tags: facebook, facebook-insights, facebook-graph-api

i am currently working with the Facebook API pulling data for an analytics platform, i have managed to retrieve everything Facebook has to provide but when it comes to

```
332405516848997/insights/page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique
332405516848997/insights/page_storytellers_by_age_gender
332405516848997/insights/page_storytellers_by_country
```

the following calls return :

```
{
  "data": [
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/332405516848997/insights/page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique?since=1374763564&until=1375022764", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/332405516848997/insights/page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique?since=1375281964&until=1375541164"
  }
}
```

My access token has the required permissons (manage pages, read insights).

I am using the Facebook [Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).

Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging to the earth's core and back i stumbled upon the following :

> **Note**: That start and end dates can be applied using since and until unix timestamps based on midnight in PST described in UTC.

Turns out it was the midnight pacific time range that was causing the issue.

[Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/)